# Tensorflow not installing, Packages do not match hash file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, failed-installation

so Ive been trying to install TensorFlow on my Rasberry Pi 3 (B) running Raspbian Strech using pip, but no matter what I try, I get the same error:

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    tensorflow from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.13.1-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl#sha256=6c00dd13db0791e83cb08d532f007cc7fd44c8d7b52662a4a0065ac4fe7ca18a:
        Expected sha256 6c00dd13db0791e83cb08d532f007cc7fd44c8d7b52662a4a0065ac4fe7ca18a
             Got        9d1adf39793da3e45661aadc026f9166e893071f4626bfa863c0ee7867dc63ba
```

This error always shows up in the middle of installation at random points

I've updated pip and tried using pip3 but none of them work...
This is wat I've tried so far:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```

and

```
sudo pip3 install tensorflow
```

Both of them show the same error

Answer (score 1):

I believe that tensorflow can only run on 64-bit python. I would check to see what version of python you are trying to install with.